# How can I recognise the argv correctly in Python cmd?

Tags: python, shell, command-line-arguments

This is the code:

```
import sys
# Gather our code in a main() function

def main():
    for arg in sys.argv:
        print(arg)

# Standard boilerplate to call the main() function to begin
# the program.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when I run it in cmd like `a.py a&7`, it only prints `a` (`&7` is not recognized).
How can I sent chars like `&` to the `sys.argv[]`?

Comment: It's sometimes helpful to include what you have tried already.

Comment: I just don`t know how to solve this kind of problem,because google seems won`t recognize special characters like '&'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On windows, escape the ampersand with a `^`:

```
python a.py a^&7
```

Or quote with double quotes (single quotes will not work):

```
python a.py "a&7"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is a Unix-like system, you'll need to quote the argument to prevent the shell from parsing it and treating `&` as a command separator:

```
a.py 'a&7'
```

Comment: @mascure: quoting command-line arguments is still a good idea on Windows.